# windows 10 and ubuntu 20.04 dual boot with portable ssd

Tags: windows-10, ssd, dualboot, ubuntu-20.04

First i installed ubuntu os to the *portable ssd*, now i want to appear dual boot option *only when i plug the portable ssd* which i installed ***ubuntu 20.04***. In here i have installed the ubuntu boot loader in same portable ssd which ubuntu installed. Can i do this? will it work successfully as i think here?  [ubuntu boot loader selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sF4XC.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using BIOS + MBR

```
Can i do this?
```

Yes

```
will it work successfully as i think here?
```

Yes  - Grub will only appear if you select to boot from that ssd

And as a note - **make sure to install it on complete ssd rather than on ubuntu partition only**

Comment: When i select one time first boot drive as the portable ssd, after remove it and mount to the laptop it will be the first boot drive. That means whenever plug the portable ssd to the laptop, I no need the setup as the first boot drive as portable ssd.

Comment: Is that a question? You can change the priority of disks in bios.Once set no need to change it on every boot. Also feel free accept the answer if it helped.